# NodeJS callback sequence

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, underscore.js, promise

Folks,
  I have the following function, and am wondering whats the correct way to call the callback() only when the database operation completes on all items:

```
function mapSomething (callback) {
    _.each(someArray, function (item) {
        dao.dosomething(item.foo, function (err, account) {
            item.email = account.email;
        });
    });
    callback();
},
```

What I need is to iterate over `someArray` and do a database call for each element.  After replacing all items in the array, I need to only then call the callback.  Ofcourse the callback is in the incorrect place right now

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not wait for all your database calls to be done before calling `callback()`.  It will launch all the database calls at once in parallel (I'm assuming that's what `dao.dosomething()` is).  And, then immediately call `callback()` before any of the database calls have finished.

You have several choices to solve the problem.

1. You can use promises (by promisifying the database call) and then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all the database calls to be done.
2. You can use the `async` library to manage the coordination for you.
3. You can keep track of when each one is done yourself and when the last one is done, call your callback.

I would recommend options 1. or 2.  Personally, I prefer to use promises and since you're interfacing with a database, this is probably not the only place you're making database calls, so I'd promisify the interface (bluebird will do that for you in one function call) and then use promises.

Here's what a promise solution could look like:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

// make promise version of your DB function
// ideally, you'd promisify the whole DB API with .promisifyAll()
var dosomething = Promise.promisify(dao.dosomething, dao);

function mapSomething (callback, errCallback) {
    Promise.all(_.map(someArray, function(item) {
        return dosomething(item.foo).then(function (account) {
            item.email = account.email;
        });
    }).then(callback, errCallback);
}
```

This assumes you want to run all the DB calls in parallel and then call the callback when they are all done.

FYI, here's [a link to how Bluebird promisify's](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) existing APIs.  I use this mechanism for all async file I/O in node and it saves a ton of coding time and makes error handling much more sane.  Async callbacks are a nightmare for proper error handling, especially if exceptions can be thrown from async callbacks.

---

P.S.  You may actually want your `mapSomething()` function to just return a promise itself so the caller is then responsible for specifying their own `.then()` handler and it allows the caller to use the returned promise for their own synchronization with other things (e.g. it's just more flexible that way).

```
function mapSomething() {
    return Promise.all(_.map(someArray, function(item) {
        return dosomething(item.foo).then(function (account) {
            item.email = account.email;
        });
    })
}

mapSomething.then(mapSucessHandler, mapErrorHandler);
```

---

I haven't tried Bluebird's `.map()` myself, but once you've promisified the database call, I think it would simplify it a bit more like this:

```
function mapSomething() {
    return Promise.map(someArray, function(item) {
        return dosomething(item.foo).then(function (account) {
            item.email = account.email;
        });
    })
}

mapSomething.then(mapSucessHandler, mapErrorHandler);
```

Comment: ofcourse, whats the correct way to write this?  async.map?

Comment: @Cmag - some general option guidance offered in my answer.  I don't see that you need `async.map()` (as you're not trying to generate a results array) so you probably would just use `async.each()`.  I prefer to use promises for this and if I was doing any async database work in my app, I'd promisify the whole API so I could use promises for all the interfaces.

Comment: Actually, you can probably use Bluebird's `.map` instead of underscore's `.map` and get rid of even the `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the first code is the [`then(success,fail)` anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-thensuccess-fail-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 3):

The way you currently have it, `callback` is executed before any of the (async) tasks finish.

The [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) module has an `each()` that allows for a final callback:

```
var async = require('async');

// ...

function mapSomething (callback) {
  async.each(someArray, function(item, cb) {
    dao.dosomething(item.foo, function(err, account) {
      if (err)
        return cb(err);
      item.email = account.email;
      cb();
    });
  }, callback);
}
```